# Can't get table to encompass all query results

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to get the table to encompass all the results returned from my query. For some reason, it only creates a new row for the first record. How can I get it to create rows for the rest of them?[picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IexVd.png)

```
<table border="2px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
            <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#c6c6c6" width="115px"> <p text-align="middle"> Region </p> </th>
            <th bgcolor="#c6c6c6" width="115px"> <p text-align="middle"> Sales </p> </th>
    </tr>
    <? while($rowR = mysqli_fetch_array($resultR)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $rowR['0'] ;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $rowR['1'] ;?> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <? } ?>
```

Comment: Your `while` end bracket is missing

Comment: It's not! I just forgot to include it when I copied my code over :(

Comment: please update so, and provide the outputted html as well

Comment: At the end of my question, there's a link to a picture of the output!

Comment: I know, that's why I ask for the outputted HTML. I can not see the html through the picture you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your end bracket `<? } ?>` for the array loop after the `</tr>` element.

By putting it after the `</table>` element, you're closing your table each time your while loop iterates.

```
<? while($rowR = mysqli_fetch_array($resultR)){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $rowR['0'] ;?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $rowR['1'] ;?> </td>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```